# How to split list item?

Tags: python

I have python list with one item like this - `[(19, 0.97471237)]`

Now i need to split it into `19` and `0.97471237`

How do i do that ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you accepted und unaccepted my answer 3 times, WeaselFox's answer 2 times, and Niklas's answer 1 time, and finally accepted Niklas's answer?

Comment: sorry. i tried to set both as correct answers ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be easy if you use pattern matching / destructuring:

```
>>> lst = [(19, 0.97471237)]
>>> lst[0]
(19, 0.97471237)
>>> x, y = lst[0]
>>> x
19
>>> y
0.97471237
```

Comment: It's not argument unpacking, it's assignment to a target list.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. My bad :(

Answer (score 2):

Use a [target list](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) for unpacking:

```
>>> [(a, b)] = [(19, 0.97471237)]
>>> a
19
>>> b
0.97471237
```

Answer (score 1):

just access the `list[0][0]` for 19 and `[0][1]` for 0.97471237. its a list of tuples.

Comment: It's a list with a tuple inside